# arrange data fetched from mysql by comma separated and count

Tags: php, mysql

I wanted to arrange a data which i fetched using a query into according to particular format . 
I am using the this query to get data

```
SELECT count(*) as number ,SUBSTRING_INDEX(REPLACE(REPLACE(Links, "http://", ""), "www.", ""), '/', 1) AS domain
FROM `encrypt`
WHERE `Folderid`='8'
group by domain
```

from this query i get the domain name such as google.com and rediff.com in domain field which i made by extracting it out from whole url and by using count i get number of same domains in result like

```
domain       number 

google.com    2
rediff.com    3
```

how to represent this data in terms for this format using mysql

```
google.com (2), rediff.com (3)
```

so that it could be like above in a new field suppose arranged_data or how to make this possible via php after getting the results ?

Comment: There's [group_concat()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat), but you should seriously consider doing such transformations in your client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alrighty, so as you loop through your results, format them and add them to an array.  Then implode that array with a ', '.

```
while ($row_get_domain_info = mysql_fetch_array($r_get_domain_info)) {

    $result_array[] = $row_get_domain_info['domain'].' ('.$row_get_domain_info['number'].')';

}

$result = implode(', ', $result_array);

print $result;
```

Comment: Warning: implode() [function.implode]: Invalid arguments passed in

Comment: Can you `print_r($result_array)` before you implode it and make sure that it's being set properly?  That error means you're trying to implode something that is not an array.  Also, check to make sure the query is returning results and that they fit your program.  I just made up the variable names `$row_get_domain_info` and `$r_get_domain_info` since that code was not included in your post.  My example will not work with copy/paste unless your names happen to be the same as mine.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( CONCAT(domain,' (',number,') '))
FROM (
SELECT count(*) as number ,SUBSTRING_INDEX(REPLACE(REPLACE(Links, "http://", ""), "www.", ""), '/', 1) AS domain
FROM `encrypt`
WHERE `Folderid`='8'
group by domain
)AS P
```

Comment: Its giving output in BLOB . and just one field :(